# How to get 2 child ID value from XML?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I wanted to try to pick up Volume value from the Level1Data node.
Here is the xml:

```
<Response>
  <Content>
    <Level1Data Tick="U" Currency="USD" TickSize="0.0001000000" TickValue="0" AssetClass="Equity" InstrumentState="Open" LastPrice="24.1550" LotSize="10"
      MinPermittedPrice="0" MaxPermittedPrice="0" ClosePrice="24.0300" OpenPrice="24.1500" FirstPrice="24.1500"
      HighPrice="24.7800" LowPrice="24.0000" MaxPrice="24.7800" MinPrice="24.0000" Volume="16238302"
      AskSize="105597" BidSize="97618" AskPrice="24.1600" BidPrice="24.1500" Symbol="BAC.NY"
      MarketTime="12:08:41.356" Message="L1DB"/>
  </Content>
</Response>
```

And then my main script:

```
<?php
$result = file_get_contents("lvl1.xml");
// echo $result;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
// $dom = new DOMDocument();
// $dom->loadXML("lvl1.xml");
// $vol = dom->getElementsByTagName('Level1Data');

$vol=$xml->children->children('Level1Data');
$id = $xml["Volume"];
echo $id;

 ?>
```

Nothing gets returned and I am having a hard time reading the php documentation and their examples.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to find the XML node using [attributes()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) and [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) what attribute you want as per your requirements. If you need only single attribute then discard foreach looping.

```
<?php
$result =<<<EOT
<Response>
      <Content>
        <Level1Data Tick="U" Currency="USD" TickSize="0.0001000000" TickValue="0" AssetClass="Equity" InstrumentState="Open" LastPrice="24.1550" LotSize="10"
          MinPermittedPrice="0" MaxPermittedPrice="0" ClosePrice="24.0300" OpenPrice="24.1500" FirstPrice="24.1500"
          HighPrice="24.7800" LowPrice="24.0000" MaxPrice="24.7800" MinPrice="24.0000" Volume="16238302"
          AskSize="105597" BidSize="97618" AskPrice="24.1600" BidPrice="24.1500" Symbol="BAC.NY"
          MarketTime="12:08:41.356" Message="L1DB"/>
      </Content>
    </Response>
EOT;

    $volume = '';
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
    foreach($xml->Content->Level1Data[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
        if($a=='Volume'){
          $volume = $b;
        }
    }
    echo $volume;
?>
```

Demo https://eval.in/839942

**OR** for single attribute e.g **Volume**

```
 echo $xml->Content->Level1Data[0]->attributes()->Volume;
```

Comment: Thank you for both solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pickup `Volume` only, it can also be done as follows.

```
<?php

$result = <<<EOM
<Response>
  <Content>
    <Level1Data Tick="U" Currency="USD" TickSize="0.0001000000" TickValue="0" AssetClass="Equity" InstrumentState="Open" LastPrice="24.1550" LotSize="10"
      MinPermittedPrice="0" MaxPermittedPrice="0" ClosePrice="24.0300" OpenPrice="24.1500" FirstPrice="24.1500"
      HighPrice="24.7800" LowPrice="24.0000" MaxPrice="24.7800" MinPrice="24.0000" Volume="16238302"
      AskSize="105597" BidSize="97618" AskPrice="24.1600" BidPrice="24.1500" Symbol="BAC.NY"
      MarketTime="12:08:41.356" Message="L1DB"/>
  </Content>
</Response>
EOM;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

echo $xml->Content->Level1Data[0]->attributes()->Volume;
```

**EDIT**

```
<?php

$result = <<<EOM
<Response>
  <Content>
    <Level1Data Tick="U" Currency="USD" TickSize="0.0001000000" TickValue="0" AssetClass="Equity" InstrumentState="Open" LastPrice="24.1550" LotSize="10"
      MinPermittedPrice="0" MaxPermittedPrice="0" ClosePrice="24.0300" OpenPrice="24.1500" FirstPrice="24.1500"
      HighPrice="24.7800" LowPrice="24.0000" MaxPrice="24.7800" MinPrice="24.0000" Volume="16238302"
      AskSize="105597" BidSize="97618" AskPrice="24.1600" BidPrice="24.1500" Symbol="BAC.NY"
      MarketTime="12:08:41.356" Message="L1DB"/>
  </Content>
</Response>
EOM;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

function recur($obj){
  if ( in_array('Level1Data', array_keys( (array) $obj->children()) ) === false){
    recur($obj->children());
  }else{
    var_dump($obj->children()->Level1Data);
    exit;
  }
}

recur($xml);
```

Comment: Thanks for the succinct answer. Just to clarify you the `$xml` variable has `<Response>` as its default root, then you keep calling the the child node till you want Level1Data then what does  `Level1Data[0]->...` represent?

Comment: Sorry I was more confused about the syntax `$xml->Content->Level1Data[0]->attributes()->Volume;` in your first post. Thanks.